# How to fix 'Missing required dependencies ['numpy']' when running packaged app made with PyInstaller?

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, pyinstaller, pipenv

When I run my packaged app I get the error `ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`. How do I fix this?

The full error:
[image: Traceback when running .exe]

I used `pyinstaller guiMain.py` to create the .exe, within a virtual environment created with `pipenv shell`. This virtual environment has `numpy 1.16.0` installed, aswell as `pandas`, `pyinstaller`, `sklearn`, `googleads` and `pytest`.

When I run the code (unpackaged and within the virtual environment) everything works fine. The packaging process goes fine aswell, until I try to run the .exe, which gives the error above.

So far I have tried:

- uninstalling and installing numpy and pandas multiple times without success.
- removing virtual environment and creating a new one and installing all required packages, without success.

I thought the error might have been caused by the recent update to the googleads package (which caused an error with pyyaml version mismatch when locking the `pipfile.lock`), but downgrading this package to 15.0.1 didn't resolve the numpy issue (it did resolve the pyyaml issue).

My Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
numpy = "*"
pandas = "*"
sklearn = "*"
pyinstaller = "*"
pytest = "*"
googleads = "==15.0.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparrently the newest version of numpy (v1.16.0) breaks something in pyinstaller, because packaging the app with numpy version 1.15.4 works fine.

Comment: Had the same issue, switching to 1.15.4 fixed it for me too.

Comment: switching to 1.15.4 did not solve my issue. can you please give more details about it. i have pandas == 0.24.2 and numpy 1.15.4 and pyinstaller = 3.4

Comment: @shubham, My problem was that packaging my project (creating a .exe file) didn't work when i had numpy 1.16.0 installed. For me, downgrading numpy to 1.15.4 worked. 
I did this inside my projects virtual environment, which i made using pipenv.
If you need any more info just ask.

Also it could be they fixed the issue in a newer version of numpy, but i am not sure since i am no longer working on this project.